# Searching by date range access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have been designing a database for the logistics department of where I work and they have asked for the ability to search for vehicles availabillity by date range.

the table
ID | Vehicle_reg | RegID | license_req | Max_Weight | Booked | Date_from | Date_to | Driver

I have a form that has the date from and date too fields for the users desired date range to book the vehicle. How can i create a query that will use the information on the form and check against the current database.

I tried to create a query using a between statement as shown below:

```
Between [Forms]![Frm_VehicleSearch]![txtDateFrom] AND [Forms]![Frm_VehicleSearch]![txtDateTo]
```

However this did not work. I'm guessing its something I've overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access dates need to be delimited with hash-signs #.

```
Between "#" & [Forms]![Frm_VehicleSearch]![txtDateFrom] & "#" AND "#" & [Forms]![Frm_VehicleSearch]![txtDateTo] & "#"
```

You may also need to format the dates to a US format. In the above expression use:

```
Format([Forms]![Frm_VehicleSearch]![txtDateFrom],"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

and the same for `txtDateTo`. An alternative format is `yyyy-mm-dd`.